# Need to add total # of orders to summary query

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

In the following, I need to add here the total of orders per order type which is IHORDT. I tried count(t01.ihordt), but its not a valid. I need this order total to get average amount per order.

Data expected:

Current:

```
IHORDT   current year     previous year
RTR      100,000             90,000
INT      2,000,000           1,500,000
```

New change: add to the above one column:

```
Total orders
RTR        100
INT        1000



SELECT  T01.IHORDT   
-- summarize by current year and previous year                                             
         ,SUM( CASE WHEN YEAR(IHDOCD)  = YEAR(CURRENT TIMESTAMP) - 1 
THEN  (T02.IDSHP#*T02.IDNTU$) ELSE 0 END) AS LastYear
         ,SUM( CASE WHEN YEAR(IHDOCD)  = YEAR(CURRENT TIMESTAMP)  
THEN  (T02.IDSHP#*T02.IDNTU$) ELSE 0 END) AS CurYear                 

     FROM ASTDTA.OEINHDIH 
     T01 INNER JOIN                                                       

     ASTDTA.OEINDLID T02                                      
     ON T01.IHORD# = T02.IDORD#          


        WHERE T01.IHORDT in ('RTR', 'INT')                                            
    --------------------------------------------------------

      AND ( YEAR(IHDOCD)  = YEAR(CURRENT TIMESTAMP) - 1 
          OR  YEAR(IHDOCD)  = YEAR(CURRENT TIMESTAMP))
     GROUP BY T01.IHORDT
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Check out SUM() over (partition by IhordT) ... seems to me that is what you need, if you can't figure it out by yourself, do as @GordonLinoff said .... Sample data and results

Comment: DB2 Version and Platform?

Answer (score 0):

To receive a count of records in a group you need to use `count(*)`.

So here is a generic example:

```
select order_type, 
       sum(order_amount) as total_sales, 
       count(*) as number_of_orders
  from order_header
  group by order_type;
```